# Scroll fields in HorizontalFieldManager

Tags: blackberry

I have a class with outer horizontalFieldManager containing next and previous buttons, between them there is a inner HFM contains 10 numbers which need to scroll when click on next and previous buttons. I have taken HFM_scroll and HFM_scrollbar fields in the constructor innerHfm and able scroll the numbers when click on them, but  I need to make scroll of numbers when click on next and previous buttons and how can I give setExtent for innerHfm so that I can place numbers in middle of next and previous.

```
hfm = new Manager(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH) {

        protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {

            layoutChild(next, maxWidth, maxHeight);
            setPositionChild(next, 300, 5);

            layoutChild(innerHfm, maxWidth, maxHeight);
            setPositionChild(innerHfm, 10, 5);

            layoutChild(previous, maxWidth, maxHeight);
            setPositionChild(previous, 44, 5);

            setExtent(maxWidth, 40);

        }
    };
```

and here is the innerHfm

```
innerHfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.HORIZONTAL_SCROLL|HorizontalFieldManager.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR) {
             protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                int space = 0;
                int x = 90;
                for (int i = 0; i < cardsSize; i++) {
                    layoutChild(numbtn[i], maxWidth, maxHeight);
                    setPositionChild(numbtn[i], x + space, 0);
                    space = space + 40;
                }
                setExtent(230, 40);
            }
                     };
```

Comment: Could you add a snippet of code to the question? Its a bit hard to see what your problem is from that description. You don't need to add all your code, just enough to illustrate your problem.

Comment: Hi Greg I added the code to get clear idea about the issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [setExtent for nested HorizontalFieldManagers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248239/setextent-for-nested-horizontalfieldmanagers)