# setExtent for nested HorizontalFieldManagers

Tags: blackberry

I am developing an application where I should use nested horizontalmanagers. I am taking inner and outer HFMs. The fields of innerHFM overlap on the outerHFM when I scroll the fields. How can I use setExtent method for innerHFM. My innerHFM contains fields like 1 2 3 4 5 and my outerHFM contains next and previous buttons. Here is the code I implemented

```
outerHFM = new HorizontalFieldManager() {

            protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {

                layoutChild(next, maxWidth, maxHeight);
                setPositionChild(next, 300, 5);

                layoutChild(innerHfm, 200, maxHeight);
                setPositionChild(innerHfm, 10, 5);

                layoutChild(previous, maxWidth, maxHeight);
                setPositionChild(previous, 44, 5);

                setExtent(maxWidth, 40);

            }
        };

    innerHfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(Manager.HORIZONTAL_SCROLL|Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH) {

        protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
            int space = 0;
            int x = 90;
            for (int i = 0; i < cardsSize; i++) {
                layoutChild(numbtn[i], 210, maxHeight);
                setPositionChild(numbtn[i], x + space+offset, 0);
                space = space + 50;
            }
            setExtent(240, 40);
        }
    };
```

Comment: I think you should override the getPreferredWidth(); of innerHFM and try your setExtent(); as setExtent(getPreferredWidth(), 40);.... not sure but may work

Answer (score 0):

Hi this sizing works for all my field managers.

```
int managerWidth;
int managerHeight;

public int getPreferredWidth() {
    return managerWidth;
}

public int getPreferredHeight() {
    return managerHeight;
}

public void sublayout(int w, int h) {
    super.sublayout(managerWidth, managerHeight);
    setExtent(managerWidth, managerHeight);
}
```

maybe that manualy positionig might be problem, you can use AbsoluteFieldManager instead...

Comment: Hi Janci! Thanks for quick reply..but when I use the above code snippet even I am not able to display the innerHFM..When I manuvally given the values I was able to get them..How can  I implement the AbsoluteFieldManager? I need to build the app from 4.6 version.